# Get all meta keys assigned to a post type

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I need to get all meta keys/custom fields that are assigned to a post type.

I don't want to get the `post_meta` values for `post_meta` assigned to a particular post, or to all posts of a post type.

But, I want to get all possible custom fields that are 'assigned' to a post type.

I have looked and I am starting to worry that it's not possible, as maybe `post_meta` isn't 'registered' but only appears in the database when a post is saved?

I want to get all post meta information for a post type, in the same way I can get all taxonomies' information, assigned to a post type.

I want to be able to do:

```
get_post_meta_information_for_post_type($post_type);
```

and get something like:

```
array('custom_meta_key_1', 'custom_meta_key_2);
```

... regardless of whether or not there is even one single existing post of that post type.

Please tell me it's possible (and how to do it :))?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Answer by @Gareth Gillman definitely works but its an expensive query if we have hundreds of posts.

The function below is less expensive and using the wp native function [get_post_custom_keys()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_keys)

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'us_get_meta_keys_for_post_type' ) ) :

    function us_get_meta_keys_for_post_type( $post_type, $sample_size = 5 ) {

        $meta_keys = array();
        $posts     = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => $post_type, 'limit' => $sample_size ) );


        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            $post_meta_keys = get_post_custom_keys( $post->ID );
            $meta_keys      = array_merge( $meta_keys, $post_meta_keys );
        }

        // Use array_unique to remove duplicate meta_keys that we received from all posts
        // Use array_values to reset the index of the array
        return array_values( array_unique( $meta_keys ) );

    }

endif;
```

You may use the $sample_size param to include more posts in the loop.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

query all posts in the post type and then get the meta keys from the posts e.g.

**Not tested, may need some amendments**

```
$meta_fields = array();
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=posttype' );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
 while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
  $the_query->the_post();

  $meta_array = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() );
  foreach( $meta_array as $meta) {
   $meta_fields = $meta[];

  } 
 }
 wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

You can then do whatever you want with the $meta_fields variable

Comment: I need be able to get all custom fields' information even if there aren't any existing posts of the post type

Comment: I don't think you can get post meta fields without a post id - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

The ID is a required field, so if you believe there are fields set outside of the posts then you would need to find another function to grab that data.

Comment: `get_post_meta()` is for getting the meta value knowing the `meta _key`. I want to get all `meta_key`s assigned to a `post type`, without knowing anything but the `post type`

Comment: I think I've figured it out... by getting all registered `meta_box`es. I'll post back if that's it

Comment: Nope I'm wrong, can't because `global $wp_meta_boxes` is only accessible from certain places :(

Comment: There's no way to reliably get all possible keys, they might be dynamically named based on data that doesn't yet exist. You can get all existing keys for existing posts, but I wouldn't suggest querying for all posts- you'll eventually run out of memory if you add lots of posts.

Comment: I think I'll have to temporarily create a post, of the required post type, and then read the meta keys that are created in the DB, and then I can delete that temporary post.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [`get_registered_meta_keys`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_registered_meta_keys/) will do the trick. Invoke it like this, `get_registered_meta_keys( 'post', $post_type )`, and it'll return an associative array of all of the meta keys and the data defines them. You can call `array_keys( get_registered_meta_keys( 'post', $post_type ) )` if you just want the keys.

I think that this is correct because the source for [`register_post_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_meta/) shows that it simply defines an `'object_subtype'` key and then delegates to `register_meta( 'post', $meta_key, $args )`. The `$object_type` arg and `object_subtype` key that are used in `register_meta` seem to line-up exactly with the args that `get_registered_meta_keys` accepts.